# Django: how do I use the form values in other python scripts?

Tags: python, django

this is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .reisplanner import *

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

def reisplanner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = reisplannerForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        beginstation = form.cleaned_data['beginstation']
        eindstation = form.cleaned_data['eindstation']

        print(beginstation, eindstation)
    else:
        form = reisplannerForm()

    return render(request, 'reisplanner.html', {'form': form})
```

---

This is `forms.py`

```
from django import forms

class reisplannerForm(forms.Form):
    beginstation = forms.CharField(required=True)
    eindstation = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

and i want to use the variables in `reisplanner.py`

```
def reisplanner():
    #
    # use the values of the form here
    #
```

I have literally tried everything, this is for a school project and have been trying to fix this for about 2 days now with no result.

If you guys could help me that would be fantastic. how do I get the values of a form to my python script?

Answer (score 0):

In `reisplanner.py`

```
def my_reisplanner(form):
    beginstation = form.cleaned_data['beginstation']
    eindstation = form.cleaned_data['eindstation']
    # Do somthing with the values
```

In `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .reisplanner import *

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

def reisplanner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = reisplannerForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        beginstation = form.cleaned_data['beginstation']
        eindstation = form.cleaned_data['eindstation']

        print(beginstation, eindstation)

        # You can call this function because you imported it in line 2
        my_reisplanner(form)
    else:
        form = reisplannerForm()

    return render(request, 'reisplanner.html', {'form': form})
```

The only problem here is the name of the function to call. If you use the same name for the view function and the process function, you will have issue with imports.

In the previous snippet, I renamed the process function to `my_reisplanner` to avoid any clash. There is other solutions if you don't want (or can't) rename the process function (see after).

In general, this kind of import is discouraged

```
from .reisplanner import *
```

as you can't control what is imported. Prefer this:

```
from .reisplanner import reisplanner as reisplanner_name_alias
# [...]
# Call reisplanner using local alias created from imports
reisplanner_name_alias()
```

or simply

```
from . import reisplanner
# [...]
# Call reisplanner using full modul dotted path
reisplanner.reisplanner()
```